# Helping Google Analytics be smarter about unique visitors

Tags: google-analytics

Our customers log in from several different computers over the course of a day, and so our unique visitor count in google analytics is really inflated.  I'd like to give GA our user ids, for example, so that it could be much smarter about this stat.  Is there any way to influence what GA considers a unique visitor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides trickery with cookies (which I wouldn't recommend), there's no "built-in" way to better inform Google Analytics to take into account multiple computers for its Unique Visitors calculations.

However, you could set the user ID in a Custom Variable, and use that to track the number of "real" unique visitors, and the distribution within the users.

```
_gaq.push(["_setCustomVar", 1, "User", user_id_string ,1]);
```

Be sure to delete this custom variable once the user signs out, both for privacy and accuracy reasons.

Answer (score 0):

GA uses two cookies __utmb and __utmc.  You can try to capture and recreate those if your users authenticate or you have a way of tracking them.